# Dropdown value returns nothing on change event

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, onchange

I am setting my dropdown value and html when a button is clicked in a for loop, as follow (which works):

```
 mySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(result[i].id).html(result[i].add));
```

but then on Change event of my dropdown I get nothing for the value, while html returns a long string, here is the change event:

```
 $('#ddlHD').change(function () {
                //var item = $('#ddlHD').val();
                // var item = $(this);
                var item = this.value;
                alert(item)
            });
```

Comment: What is #ddlHD? The select element?

Comment: @Sam Are you creating the complete drop down dynamically? If it is dynamic, you have use 'on' method instead of 'change'.

Comment: @roasted yes it is the dropdown.

Comment: @aravindtrue no not the dropdown im just setting visibility of it on ready function and populate it on ready function using above code

Comment: Post relevant html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your event handler is added before the select is in the DOM then you'll need to do it this way:

```
$(document).on('change', '#ddlHD', function () {
     var item = this.value;
     alert(item)
});
```

Your current event handler code would only work if the select is available in the DOM at the time of assigning the handler.

Comment: tried your version still same thing....do I do this in ready function? I am populating the dropdown on ready.

Comment: @Sam, verify the select has an id `ddlHD`. That would be the only reason my code won't work.

Comment: ah looking at the firebug the dropdown is like this <option value="">Option 1</option>.....so no value...my next question would be how do I set a value if the line above to populate drop down doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
       $('#ddlHD').on("change",function () {
            //var item = $('#ddlHD').val();
            // var item = $(this);
            var item = this.value;
            alert(item)
        });
```

If you are adding items dynamically means after DOM loading then you need to get that items on `on` event.

Hope it helps you

Comment: i still get nothing..the indexchange fires but alert returns nothing

Comment: @Sam Hey could you please post you dropdown html after appending the items so that i can test more better way.

Comment: Do you mean the select options or dropdown html?

Comment: Yes i want select option of drop down

Comment: <option value="">Option 1</option> just got this with firebug and value is empty so i assume the problem is in populating the drop down

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

New jQuery versions (1.9+):

```
$('#ddlHD').on("change", function () {
     //var item = $('#ddlHD').val();
     // var item = $(this);
     var item = this.value;
     alert(item)
});
```

Old jQuery versions (Below 1.9):

```
$('#ddlHD').live("change", function () {
     //var item = $('#ddlHD').val();
     // var item = $(this);
     var item = this.value;
     alert(item)
});
```

Comment: i still get nothing..the indexchange fires but alert returns nothing